# How can I get latency info from Android's AudioTrack class?

Tags: android, audio

I've noticed that the C++ classes underlying the `AudioTrack` and `AudioRecord` APIs in Android both have a `latency()` method that is not exposed via JNI. As far as I can see, the `latency()` method in `AudioRecord` still does not take into account the hardware latency (they have a TODO comment for that), but the `latency()` method in `AudioTrack` does add in the hardware latency.

I absolutely need to get this latency value from `AudioTrack`. Is there any possible way I can do this? I don't care what kind of crazy hack is needed as long as it doesn't require a rooted phone (the resulting code must still be packaged as an app on the market).

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `AudioTrack` called `getLatency()` that you can invoke via reflection. For an example, look at Exoplayer or https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/audio-video-synchronization.html#section1-2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but do you need the real buffer + hardwre latency?
Unfortunately it seems you won´t be able to get this value unless you use some hacks not recommended by google and which can turn into creases in new Android versions.

Comment: what hacks are you refering too ?